# Condition for Open Sets

Tags: general-topology

How can one verify that $U$ is open iff $\overline{B} \cap U \subset \overline{B\cap U}$  for any subset $B?$. I have attempted, and I just want to know if I am going in the correct direction.

**Proof:** Let U be open, we have $B \cap U \subset \overline{B\cap U}$, since U is open, any limit point of $B$ contained in $U$ must also be a limit point of $B \cap U.$ Thus we have $B'\cap U \subset (B\cap U)' \subset \overline{B\cap U} $, which further implies $\overline{B}\cap U=(B \cap U)\cup(B'\cap U )\subset \overline {B\cap U}$

This is just one way, for the other direction, I am not quite sure how to show. Can anyone help me out further, and also if the above is not correct, could anyone help me show this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $U$ is not open.
Then $U^c$ is not closed, which means that $U^c$ is a proper subset of $\overline{U^c}$.
Consequently $\overline{U^c}\cap U$ is nonempty. Since $\overline{U^c\cap U}=\emptyset$, we have that
$\overline{U^c}\cap U \not\subseteq \overline{U^c\cap U}.$

Comment: So I am confused, is my proof correct? Or is this the other direction?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Yes, your proof is fine and this is for the other direction.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Conversely set B = $U^c.$  Then
$\overline U^c \cap U = \overline {U \cap U^c}$ is empty.
Thus U subset $U^o$ which assures U is open.

Comment: @Willaim Elliot Thank You